Blazor Development: How to Quickly Navigate to CSS Class Definition
I come from a WPF/UWP dev background, and as such, I'm used to the "XAML-way" of doing things when approaching Razor and CSS development in a Blazor context.
Perhaps I was spoiled in this regard in the XAML world, but it was an instantaneous thing to have the cursor on a xaml element, see that there was a particular Style applied, then hit F12 to navigate to that style's definition.
What is the equivalent workflow when on an HTML element in a .razor file, seeing a certain CSS class that is applied, and wanting to navigate to its definition?
It seems that there is no keyboard shortcut for this (i.e. go-to definition and peek definition commands do nothing in a razor context), so what is a fast workflow for this?
I can do it the arduous way of CTRL+F and fiddling with that Find dialog, but c'mon--there's got to be a better way. Surely, folks who develop Blazor frontends all day every day (and are navigating to CSS class definitions hundreds of times per day) have fast workflow for this common move.

Actually, this is according to your visual studio version, if you are using the visual studio code, there is a lot of extension which contains go to definition feature like below:
Html CSS support:

But if you are using visual studio, there is no such extension which could work in VS 2022. Only one is just working for the VS2019 and before.]
HTML TOOL 2019


Yeah, sorry, I love VS Code and did a trial run comparing the two, but VS 2022 won for Blazor dev by a landslide (even considering the extensions you mentioned for Code)

OK but for VS2022 there is no extension currently which could achieve your requirement.
